# How to install Windows 8.1 on new PC with SSD

Tags: boot, installation, windows-8.1, ssd

I just build new PC and trying to install Windows 8.1 from DVD (USB DVD ROM). I tried many different ways which from the internet but nothing is working.

**First attempt**

UEFI installation. Boot priority to UEFI CD/DVD ROM, in Windows setup in CMD I create necessary partitions:

```
select disk 0
clean
convert gpt
create partition primary size=300
format quick fs=ntfs label="Windows RE tools"
assign letter="T"
create partition efi size=100
rem == Note: for Advanced Format Generation One drives, change to size=260.

format quick fs=fat32 label="System"
assign letter="S"
create partition msr size=128
create partition primary
format quick fs=ntfs label="Windows"
assign letter="W"
```

Installation continue but after restart it again boot the DVD and start the setup. It won't boot from SSD disk, even if I made it only available option for boot. I presume it the option UEFI Windows Boot Manager is missing and don't know why.

**Second attempt**

Disable all UEFI boot priorities, left only CD/DVD ROM and create one partition in CMD

> diskpart
>   list disk
>   select disk n [where n = SSD]
>   clean
>   create partition primary
>   select partition 1
>   active
>   format fs=ntfs
>   assign
>   exit

When I get to choose where to install I cannot install on SSD with this error message:

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may
>   not support booting to this disk. Ensure the disk's controller is
>   enabled in the computer's BIOS menu.

I don't know what to try next, please help.

HW: Motherboard MSI H97 Gaming 3
SDD INTEL 520 120GB

Answer (score 1):

Go back into `diskpart`, and clean the disk. Then, continue on with the Windows installation.

When it gets to the point of asking you what disk to install it to, choose the **Unallocated Space**, and let it create the partition scheme it needs.

The typical Windows Vista/7/8 install requires more than just one giant NTFS volume, although that's what most people just see (since it gets assigned the `C:\` usually).

Comment: thanks for answer. But should I boot the CD/DVD ROM in UEFI or Legacy mode? And the SSD shoud be GPT or MBR?

Comment: Doesn't matter, but if you want the efi version, boot in efi mode

Answer (score 1):

It would have been easiest to just leave the disk empty, and let Windows create all the appropriate partitions. However
I too prefer to set up the drive manually, that way you can configure it all how you like it.

## Install Windows With A Manually Setup Partition Scheme:

[image: step1]

1. Boot up the Windows 8.1 installation disc, enter your desired language, keyboard, time, and 
   currency settings; click `Next`.

[image: step2]
[image: step2b]
[image: step2c]
[image: step2d]

2. Click `Repair your computer`, click `Troublshoot`, click `Advanced options`, and then click `Command Prompt`.

[image: step3]

3. In the Command Prompt, type `diskpart`, `select disk #`, `convert gpt`, `create partition efi size=512`, 
   `select partition 1`, and `format quick fs=fat32 label="ESP"`. You will need to substitute `disk #` for the
   disk you wish to install on, such as `disk 0`. Typically an E.S.P. (EFI System Partition) is 100 megabytes, but
   if you like to multiboot you can run out of room so some people, like me, use a larger size. The E.S.P. is usually
   labelled as `System`, at least by Microsoft, but it doesn't matter what you call it; personally I prefer `ESP`.

[image: step4]

4. In Diskpart, type `select disk #`, and `create partition msr size=128`. The M.S.R. (Microsoft Reserved Partition)
   is used by legacy applications that need hidden sectors, G.P.T.s (GUID Partition Table) do not allow hidden sectors
   so this partition is used instead.

[image: step5]

5. In Diskpart type `select disk #`, `create partition primary`, and `format quick fs=ntfs label="OSP"`. Most people
   would use the label `Windows`, but you can call it what-ever you like.

[image: step6]

6. In Diskpart type `exit`, then in the Command Prompt type `setup.exe`, and then refill in the language, currency, time,
   and keyboard settings you want; click `Next`.

[image: step7]

7. Accept the license agreement, and click `Next`.

[image: step8]

8. You will want to choose a `Custom: Install Windows only (advanced)` installation type.

[image: step9]

9. Click on the 3 partition, it should be your primary partition that you previously made, labelled O.S.P., and 
   click `Next`.

[image: step10]
[image: step10b]

10. The installer will copy the files over, and install them; this will take a while. Then the computer will
    restart, and you can remove the installation disc; the computer needs to boot from your hard drive.

[image: step11]

11. Once Windows boots up it will do some setting up; this will take a few minutes. The computer will reboot, again.

[image: step12]
[image: step12b]

12. You will see the loading screen for a few minutes, and then reach the `Personalize` screen. Choose a color scheme,
    a name for your computer `example`, and then click `Next`.

[image: step13]
[image: step13b]
[image: step13c]
[image: step13d]
[image: step13e]

13. On the `Settings` screen choose `Customize`, unless you wish to use the `Express Settings`, and then choose your
    desired options on each screen presented.

[image: step14]
[image: ste14b]

14. When you reach the account creation screen you will be prompted to sign into your `Microsoft account`, or create one.
    If you would like to do so proceed, but I will be covering how to use a local account. Please note that using a local
    account will prevent you from installing apps from the Microsoft Store. To create a local account click `create new
    account`. On the `Create a Microsoft account` screen, do not fill in anything, just click `Sign in without a Microsft
    account`.

[image: step15]

15. On the `Your account` screen you can now create a local account. Pick a username, password, and password hint. Click
    `Finish`.

[image: step16]
[image: step16b]
[image: step16c]
[image: step16d]

16. You will be welcomed, and then Windows will do some more setting up; oooh pretty colors.

[image: step17]

17. You will be automatically logged in, and greeted by the start screen. You have successfully installed Windows 8.1.

Comment: thanks for answer. But in step 8 it says another problem, 'windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style.'. I don't know how to avoid it now. any suggestions?

Comment: If I boot DVD in UEFI style, I avoid the problem message and continue to install, but after restart it won't boot from SSD. no UEFI: Windows Boot Manager... still not working

Comment: @mascot Boot up the installation disc, open the Command Prompt, type `diskpart`, `select disk #` (use the # for your ESP, should be 1), `assign letter=q`, `exit`, and then `notepad`. Go to `File`, `Open`, then browse the `q` drive. You will need to change `files of type:` to `All Files` to see anything; if the drive has files/folders on it then your ESP was setup during installation.

Comment: @mascot If you wish to install on a GPT drive layout then you must boot in UEFI mode. Did you remember to remove the installation disc in step 10? Check your boot order to make sure you're booting from the correct device. How many drives does your computer have? Do you have more than 1 ESP (EFI System Partition) currently?

Comment: I can see files on ESP drive. But the problem is I think it can't boot the SSD in UEFI. When I go to boot menu I can see the SSD, but only the Legacy. If I turn off Legacy, I can't see the SSD. So instead of booting i get message "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected".

Comment: @mascot I'm not sure why it's doing that, but if you have any other hard drives, card readers, or usb sticks attached you might try disconnecting them, re-installing, and see if the same issue occurs.