# Windows 8 Install on new SSD using recovery USB failed (ASUS)

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

On my ASUS X551M laptop my old harddrive failed (as said by ASUS tech support).
Before that they suggested to trying to recover the HD and tried but finally they said HDD issue.
Replaced a new SSD.

When trying to install Windows from recovery USB onto new SSD I am getting error.
Steps followed:
1) Replaced new SSD out of the box
2) Changed the boot priority to UEFI - USB drive
3) Some automatic process and then suggested to remove the USB
4) Then system automatically restarted and now some process
5) This is where I see the "**[Error] Apply OS fail!**"
Attaching error images.[image: Error Screen][image: Screen before error]

This is where I stuck can some please help.

From here [Windows exe download](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1800781/windows-iso-file.html?579cf4c2059b0=reload) I tried to get the Windows 8 exe but unable to install with these Windows exe.

Comment: Did Asus suggest that SSD?  If they did, you should call them back.

Comment: I contacted Asus tech support, they tried to help as laptop is out of warranty and it is not original part I cannot request for RMA as well. That is where I started seeking help here.

Comment: OK.  Then that explains your recovery error.  Would you care to clarify what stops you from making a fresh Windows 8 installation?  If it's in any way related to an activation or license key, you'll need to contact Microsoft.

Comment: As I was unable to find the Windows 8.1 ISO link to make a fresh bootable USB. Can anyone share Windows 8.1 ISO link to download. With link Windows exe I was unable to make bootable USB. About activation / license key I will contact ASUS first.

Comment: Doesn't the one from the link included in your question work ( http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=271128 )?

Comment: With that exe and unable to create bootable USB. May be I will give a try one more time today and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Microsoft technical support help resolve the issue.

Steps I have followed (started fresh again after the above mentioned error in question)

1. Downloaded [**Media Creation tool**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8) from Microsoft website
2. Installed Windows 8.1 using USB created above
3. Used generic key as suggested in [**askvg**](http://www.askvg.com/fix-windows-8-genuine-product-key-doesnt-work-for-windows-8-1-clean-installation/) website.
4. After successful installation I tried activate Windows8.1 with valid
   product key, but I was getting error as "**That key can't be used to
   activate this edition of windows. please try a different key**"
5. Here Microsoft team helped me to get New product key helped for complete installation.

I could able to upgrade to Windows 10 now.

**Helpful resources
- [How to install Windows 8.1 on new PC with SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/834765/how-to-install-windows-8-1-on-new-pc-with-ssd)**

**[Clean install Windows 8.1 or Windows 8 from OEM key](https://superuser.com/questions/697253/clean-install-windows-8-1-or-windows-8-from-oem-key)**

Comment: I doubt it is acceptable to encourage people to use serial numbers they didn't pay for.

Comment: You are talking about the Keys provided above? Even though we use obviously you will see that Windows is not active, after you login. You have to provide a valid product key to activate your windows.